# Bluetooth connection - will not auto pair/reconnect to audio device

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Bluetooth 4.99 & bluez.

My audio device is paired successfully. However, on the second attempt to connect there is no auto pairing.  I have to issue:

```
bluez-test-audio connect <address>
```

each and every time to reconnect.

All values for adapter annd device are correct in /var/lib/bluetooth.

Spent hours/days on this!  Help please!

---

added:

root@debian:~# dir /var/lib/bluetooth/00:1B:10:00:05:94
classes  did  features  lastused  manufacturers  profiles  trusts
config   eir  lastseen  linkkeys  names          sdp

---

edit:  I enabled Autoconnect in audio.conf - makes no difference ... or should I delete the whole bluetooth settings, and restart the pairing again?

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Can you add the contents of /var/lib/bluetooth to your question?

Comment: Here's what's in /var/lib/bluetooth for the specific adapter:

Comment: oops - added above

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add:

Disable = Media

into "General" section of /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf

with this my bluetooth headsets connect/reconnect again without problem.

It's not from my head, I found a hint in one post on spanish raspberry pi forum.

Comment: This does not work and it even blocks connecting manually.