# Bluetooth unable to reconnect to paired phone (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10, phone, a2dp, bluez

I have an Asus laptop with no built-in Bluetooth, so I bought a Bluetooth dongle which works perfectly: I'm perfectly able to connect to my phone and play music from my phone through my laptop speaker.
The only problem is that once my phone and my laptop are paired, I'm not able to reconnect them, once they are disconnected, without having to delete the pairing both on the phone and on the laptop, and pair them again.

Googling, I found that the issue might be fixed by adding the `Enable=Sink` line to the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file, but that file doesn't exist already and creating it didn't seem to fix the issue.

Also the answer to this question is not applyable, since there is no `audio.conf` file
[Bluetooth connection - will not auto pair/reconnect to audio device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253399/bluetooth-connection-will-not-auto-pair-reconnect-to-audio-device)

I'm running `Ubuntu 15.10` with `bluez 5.35`, and my phone is a Nokia `Lumia 920` running `Windows phone 8.1`.